# Genetic algorithm to find minimum of a function of 2 variables

Tags: mathematical-optimization, genetic-algorithm

I'm studying GA and i wanted to implent it to find a minimum of a f(x,y)
ex. z=sin3x+cos4y
Now, my problem is how i should treat chromosome x and y. Should they be 2 separate population? Should they be encoded in the same chromosome?

Comment: Hi, and welcome. I'm afraid this question may be closed as it requires specific domain knowledge. If you could simplify the question into a programming problem, we may be able to assist.

Comment: If you aren't writing any code yet, this will probably be off-topic here.  However by the sounds of your question it may be better to ask it over at Cross Validated SE instead.  Just check their help first at http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/ to make sure it's on-topic there.

Comment: I'm going to put some time into figuring this one out, but if you find an answer backed up with research, let me know. I am really interested in the solution to this, but I think that a GA is not the best approach to solving the problem. However, if I had to bet I would say make a composite individual.

Comment: See the last comment on this: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164490/genetic-algorithm-to-find-minimum-of-a-function-of-2-variables

Comment: PSO is likely to be the better choice in this scenario I'd say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - your function is separable. This means that you can optimize each dimension (x and y) separately - you fix e.g. y to 0 and you focus only on x and find minimum. Then you fix x and find minimum in y. Then you are done. If your function was not separable, you couldn't do that. The simplest example of an unseparable function is f(x, y) = xy.

To the GA stuff - it depends on what you mean by GA. If you really mean the classical GA evolving binary strings than that is a bad approach in real-valued optimization. Much much much better approach is to use a real-valued GA (or EA to be more precise). In that one the genotype is made of the real numbers themselves, i.e. both x and y (because both of them are a solution, not just one of them). You of course need to employ different mutation and crossover operators. Look at a [post](http://zegkljan.blogspot.cz/2015/07/evolution-in-computer-pt-2.html) on my blog where I write exactly about that (you can safely skip to the "Real-valued Evolution" part).

Comment: What if the function is not separable?

Comment: @Christian That is the case most of the time. If it is not separable you have to optimize in all dimensions at the same time. That means that both the x and y (and others if your function even more dimensional) are all part of a single solution and you evolve these. For your function, one individual (genotype/chromosome/...) would be a pair of numbers, e.g. (3.1, -7.063). Is it clearer?